# Java - Deserialization issue for ResponseEntity as a response

Tags: java, spring

I'm attempting to set up a stub endpoint and a caller for it in a separate app.  By design, the endpoint needs to return something very simple - very basic response with status code 200 or 500 - no extra response objects are required. Currently the caller of the endpoint is throwing the error below. It is too early to tell what kind of MediaType the endpoint will return, but currently I have it set to json as follows:

The error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

The endpoint definition:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/runtest")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    ResponseEntity runtest(MyRequestObject obj);
```

And a stub endpoint implementation:

```
    public ResponseEntity runtest(MyRequestObject obj) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
```

The caller code in a separate application utilizing the endpoint:

```
    public ResponseEntity runtest(MyRequestObject obj) {
        return service.runtest(obj);
    }
```

When I hit the endpoint with just the Postman, I get back what I would expect without any errors:

```
{
    "headers": {...},
    "body": null,
    "statusCodeValue": 200,
    "statusCode": "OK"
}
```

Here is what I'm hoping to resolve:

- Is there a simple way to get the above to work, without attaching a DTO object to the ResponseEntity? The response needs to be very basic.
- I'd rather not set MediaType for ResponseEntity, but it seems to me that I have to have it to match the definition of the endpoint.

Much appreciate your input and time.

Comment: Hi, what are you using as rest client? `RestTemplate`? Does the error happen on server side? caller side?

Comment: Maybe try typing the `ResponseEntity` as `ResponseEntity<Void>`. I think you wouldnt need to specify the media type, nor Spring should try to make any conversions

Comment: You don't have to include the `contentType` in a `ResponseEntity` as you already defined it in the annotation of the endpoint. Also what object are you returning in the `ResponseEntity`?

Comment: @Jhilton - The error is on the caller side. The http client used in the caller is javax.ws.rs.client. If i use ResponseEntity<Void> and remove everything related to Media Type, I get this error just calling the endpoint via Postman: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity of media type: application/octet-stream

Comment: Sorry, I would need to setup a project to test around for a really proper answer, the quick and dirty way might be to "produce" text plain, have the ResponseEntity as `ResponseEntity<String>`, and just assume the text is always empty, or not look for the response body at all on caller's side

Comment: @AP11 - I'm not attaching any object to ResponseEntity, I hope I could keep it as is.

Comment: @user2917629 Then, as @Jhilton suggested, just change it to `ResponseEntity<Void>` so it knows that no body should be attached to it.
Then you should return only this `return ResponseEntity.ok();`

Comment: @AP11 - I've tried with void, it didn't work. I got this error just calling the endpoint via Postman: org.jboss.resteasy.core.NoMessageBodyWriterFoundFailure: Could not find MessageBodyWriter for response object of type: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity of media type: application/octet-stream

Comment: You are mixing a Spring `ResponseEntity` with JAX-RS which doesn't know what to do with it. So either stop using `ResponseEntity` as that is for Spring not for JAX-RS or ditch JAX-RS and use Spring MVC instead.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thank you, yes, I'm going to try replacing  ResponseEntity with just Response next.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the deserialization error, this custom Json object Cancellation is returned instead of ResponseEntity:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/runtest")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    Cancellation runtest(MyRequestObject obj);
```